# Angular check radio button using object as value

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm build a form on Angular 5 and I have a set of radio buttons divided by groups, I want to check these radio buttons based on an object value. This is my code so far:

**.ts**

```
constructor(
    private _params: ActivatedRoute,
) {
    _params.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
        this.param = param;
    });

    this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
        'filter': new FormControl(this.param, [
            Validators.required,
        ])
    });
}
```

**.html**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="filterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <article>
        <h4>Model</h4>

        <fieldset *ngFor="let item of models; let i = index">
            <input id="M{{i}}" type="radio" formControlName="filter" [value]="{model: item.url}" />
            <label for="M{{i}}"><span></span> {{item.name}}</label>
        </fieldset>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h4>Type</h4>

        <fieldset *ngFor="let item of types; let i = index">
            <input id="T{{i}}" type="radio" formControlName="filter" [value]="{type: item.url}" />
            <label for="T{{i}}"><span></span> {{item.name}}</label>
        </fieldset>
    </article>

    <article>
        <h4>Color</h4>

        <fieldset *ngFor="let item of colors; let i = index">
            <input id="C{{i}}" type="radio" formControlName="filter" [value]="{color: item.url}" />
            <label for="C{{i}}"><span></span> {{item.name}}</label>
        </fieldset>
    </article>

    <button>Apply filter</button>
</form>
```

When the form is initialized, before I click in any radio button option, I can get the form value the way it's supposed to be, for example:

```
{color: "Blue"};
```

When I click on a radio button, same thing happens, it works as expected, giving the correct output and keeo the selection as expected.

The problem is when I first initalize the form, then no radio button is marked as selected. Only after the first click.

Since the form is also inside a div with ngIf to show/hide the options to filter, when I hide and show, the button lose it's selection again.

---

So, if I already have a param on the URL and pass it to the form, the radio button will not be selected. I expected it to be selected, because the form value and the value on the `[value]` property are the same. If I click on the same button to select, the form value keeps the same.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: `[value]="{color: item.url}"` is essentially initiating a new object here, which will definitely be different than the object `this.param`, albeit they may have the same literal presentation.

Comment: @HarryNinh But, is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: There is but onerous I'd say. First make a list of possible selections in your ts `this.colorOptions = this.colors.map(item => return {color: item.url})`, then populate the form control value by looked up object in that list `let theOption = this.colorOptions.find(i => i.color === this.param.color); ...'filter': new FormControl(theOption)`

Comment: I'm trying to understand the setup here. You are using the same FormControl for each iteration? Please crate a demo which showcases this issue, since right now this doesn't seem to make sense on what you are trying to achieve? :)